# I don't need a full solution but i need guidance for the solution

Tags: binomial-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution, discrete-distributions

[image]

I don't need a full solution but I need guidance for the solution.

Comment: We are happy to oblige, but you need to get us started by showing what progress you have made and pointing to a specific issue to address.